# Is it possible to include -T option of scp in .ssh/config?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, openssh, scp

scp with the -T option does this (openssh implementation):

```
Disable strict filename checking.  By default when copying files from a
remote host to a local directory scp checks that the received filenames
match those requested on the command-line to prevent the remote end from
sending unexpected or unwanted files.  Because of differences in how
various operating systems and shells interpret filename wildcards, these
checks may cause wanted files to be rejected.  This option disables
these checks at the expense of fully trusting that the server will not
send unexpected filenames.
```

I'd like to always have -T for scp for a particular host so would like to include it in .ssh/config but can't find an option for it. Is it possible?

Note that this is different from the -t option of ssh, which is clearly possible with RequestTTY.

Comment: There is no `-T` option in [scp(1): secure copy - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp)

Comment: I should have specified I'm talking about the openssh implementation. That scp does have a -T option: https://man.openbsd.org/scp

Comment: `scp` uses `ssh` as a transport. I believe it does not use `.ssh/config` directly. It calls `ssh` and then `ssh` uses the file. It's possible to pass options from the calling process (`scp`) to the child (`ssh`) but not the other way around. The option you want is specific to `scp`. If `scp` could be configured by `.ssh/config`, why not other programs? The premise is any program can use `ssh` as a transport. For now I think it's impossible to use `.ssh/config` the way you want. *Maybe* there is some clever way. I'm looking forward to being surprised.